# Could not save image in external directory

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream

I could not save Image in external directory in my android app. I practices myself and searched for the same problem but nothing could help me.
All i want to do is display a dialog with that image, and give user a option to save it and if saved view it.
But it always catches a null pointer exception at out.flush(); in Marshmallow and upper.
Works fine in lollipop.
permissions added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Code seems fine to me. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
private void display_image(String url, String title) {

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_display_images);
        dialog.setTitle(title);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        layoutParams.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());

        layoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

        dialog.show();
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.image_here);
        final InputStream in;
        Bitmap img=null;
        final Bitmap imgcpy;

        try {
            in = getAssets().open(url);
            img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            iv.setImageBitmap(img);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        imgcpy = img;

        final FloatingActionButton save = (FloatingActionButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.fab_save);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File dir = new File(filePath + "/app_images");
                dir.mkdirs();
                Random generate = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generate.nextInt(n);
                String fName = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";

                final File file = new File(dir, fName);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    file.delete();
                }
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    imgcpy.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setTitle("Image Saved Successfully")
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_save)
                            .setMessage("Image saved at: " + file.getAbsolutePath())
                            .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            })
                            .setPositiveButton("Open", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Opening...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath()), "image/*");
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            })
                            .create().show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Could not save image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Could not save image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

API level 6.0 or above you need runtime permission:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
            new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_EXT_STORAGE);
}
```

And override this method in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Constant.REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
            if (grantResults!=null) {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    //Call ur save method here 
                } else {
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Please enable write permission from ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to create directory and image file:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    // Create an image file name
    Random generate = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generate.nextInt(n);

    String nValue = String.valueOf(n);
    String fName = "Image-" + n;


    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File dir = new File(filePath + "/app_images");

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            fName,          /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            dir             /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.e("mCurrentPhotoPath", mCurrentPhotoPath + "  ++++"); //Prints you the image file path
    return image;
}
```

And call the above method like this wherever you want:

```
try {
     //photoFile = createImageFile();
     File photoFile = createImageFile();
} catch (IOException ex) {
  // Error occurred while creating the File
  ex.printStackTrace();
  Log.e("IO_EX", ex + "");
}
```

And in the manifest give these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

All the best!